# OpenLG glAttachShader not working

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader

I have a proble, which is that Im compiling and using my shader just like in a tutorail but glAttachShader does not work my return value(if I check it) is 0 but compiling was successful.
Can anyone help me ?

This is a part of my code :

```
  fragment_shaderID = CompileShader("/home/nikolaij/Schreibtisch/MOTOR/shader.frag", 1000, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  vertex_shaderID = CompileShader("/home/nikolaij/Schreibtisch/MOTOR/shader.vert", 1000, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

  shader_programID = makeShaderProgram(vertex_shaderID, fragment_shaderID);

  shader_programID = glCreateProgram();

  glAttachShader(shader_programID, fragment_shaderID);
  glAttachShader(shader_programID, vertex_shaderID);

  glLinkProgram(shader_programID);

  int attach = 0;
  glGetShaderiv(fragment_shaderID, GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS, &attach);

  printf("ATTACH : %i\n", attach);

  glUseProgram(shader_programID);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `glGetShaderiv` function does not accept `GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS` as a parameter.  You should be getting a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error, which you would notice if you were using `KHR_debug` (or some alternative, like `glGetError()`).

Besides, a shader doesn't have attached shaders.  Only programs have attached shaders.  Here is the corrected version:

```
int num_attached;
glGetProgramiv(shader_programID, GL_ATTACHED_SHADERS, &num_attached);
```

I strongly recommend using `KHR_debug`, as you would have discovered the error immediately.  Or at least use `glGetError()`, but this won't give you as much information.

Comment: @noName: How am I supposed to know what's causing that?  You asked for help with `glAttachShader()`.  Now you have a completely different problem which has nothing to do with `glAttachShader()`.  There are probably a hundred reasons why your screen could be black.  http://retokoradi.com/2014/04/21/opengl-why-is-your-code-producing-a-black-window/